# TypeScript: Generics type definition for TypedArray

Tags: javascript, generics, typescript, typed-arrays

I am trying to write a function that expands / shrinks TypedArray by taking an arbitrary TypedArray as an input and returns a new same-typed TypedArray with a different size and copy original elements into it.

For example, when you pass, `new Uint32Array([1,2,3])` with new size of `5`, it will return `new Uint32Array([1,2,3,0,0])`.

```
export const resize = <T>(
    source: ArrayLike<T>, newSize: number,
): ArrayLike<T> => {
    if (!source.length) { return new source.constructor(newSize); }
    newSize = typeof newSize === "number" ? newSize : source.length;
    if (newSize >= source.length) {
        const buf = new ArrayBuffer(newSize * source.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
        const arr = new source.constructor(buf);
        arr.set(source);
        return arr;
    }
    return source.slice(0, newSize);
};
```

While the code works as expected, TSC is complaining that 1) ArrayType does not have `BYTES_PER_ELEMENT` and `slice`, and 2) `Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature` for the statement `new source.constructor()`.

Is there a way to specify type interfaces for such function that TSC understands my intention?

For 1), I understand ArrayLike does not have interface defined for TypedArray but individual typed array does not seem to inherit from a common class... For instance, instead of using generics, I can use `const expand = (source: <Uint32Array|Uint16Array|...>): <Uint32Array|Uint16Array|...> => {}`. But it loses context of returning type being same type of the source array.

And for 2) I am clueless on how to tackle this error. It seems reasonable for TSC to complain that source's constructor is lacking type information. But if I can pass proper type for 1), I presume 2) will be disappeared too.

ref) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't beautitiful, but it works:

```
type TypedArray = ArrayLike<any> & {
    BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: number;
    set(array: ArrayLike<number>, offset?: number): void;
    slice(start?: number, end?: number): TypedArray;
};
type TypedArrayConstructor<T> = {
    new (): T;
    new (size: number): T;
    new (buffer: ArrayBuffer): T;
    BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: number;
}

export const resize = <T extends TypedArray>(source: T, newSize: number): T => {
    if (!source.length) {
        return new (source.constructor as TypedArrayConstructor<T>)();
    }

    newSize = typeof newSize === "number" ? newSize : source.length;

    if (newSize >= source.length) {
        const buf = new ArrayBuffer(newSize * source.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
        const arr = new (source.constructor as TypedArrayConstructor<T>)(buf);
        arr.set(source);
        return arr;
    }
    return source.slice(0, newSize) as T;
};
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20TypedArray%20%3D%20ArrayLike%3Cany%3E%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20BYTES_PER_ELEMENT%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20set(array%3A%20ArrayLike%3Cnumber%3E%2C%20offset%3F%3A%20number)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20slice(start%3F%3A%20number%2C%20end%3F%3A%20number)%3A%20TypedArray%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20TypedArrayConstructor%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20()%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20(buffer%3A%20ArrayBuffer)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20BYTES_PER_ELEMENT%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20resize%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20TypedArray%3E(source%3A%20T%2C%20newSize%3A%20number)%3A%20T%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(!source.length)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20(source.constructor%20as%20TypedArrayConstructor%3CT%3E)()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20newSize%20%3D%20typeof%20newSize%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22number%22%20%3F%20newSize%20%3A%20source.length%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(newSize%20%3E%3D%20source.length)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20buf%20%3D%20new%20ArrayBuffer(newSize%20*%20source.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20arr%20%3D%20new%20(source.constructor%20as%20TypedArrayConstructor%3CT%3E)(buf)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20arr.set(source)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20arr%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20source.slice(0%2C%20newSize)%20as%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A))

Comment: Thanks Nitzan, I will use your implementation with considering @tamas-hegedus' thought. I think typecasting is acceptable for this use case as unit testing can easily cover corner cases.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply define a generic `TypedArray` in a declaration file.

1- Create a file named `extras.d.ts` in your app.

2- Add the following line:

```
type TypedArray = Int8Array | Uint8Array | Int16Array | Uint16Array | Int32Array | Uint32Array | Uint8ClampedArray | Float32Array | Float64Array;
```

Then the generic `TypedArray` type will be available throughout your project. You can use this `extras.d.ts` file to keep declaring more custom types to use throughout your app.

Answer (score 2):

I grabbed @Nitzan's answer and massaged it until all the type-casts was gone, BUT unfortunately this solution suffers from the [untyped constructor property issue here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841), and there seem to be no workaround without type-casts. I post the code anyway for future reference.

**Warning: this code does not compile as of 2017/05/16.**

```
interface GenericTypedArray<T> extends ArrayLike<number> {
    BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: number;
    set(array: ArrayLike<number>, offset?: number): void;
    slice(start?: number, end?: number): T;
    constructor: GenericTypedArrayConstructor<T>;
}

interface GenericTypedArrayConstructor<T> {
    new (): T;
    new (buffer: ArrayBuffer): T;
}

export function resize<T extends GenericTypedArray<T>>(source: T, newSize: number): T {
    if (!source.length) {
        return new source.constructor();
    }

    newSize = typeof newSize === "number" ? newSize : source.length;

    if (newSize >= source.length) {
        const buf = new ArrayBuffer(newSize * source.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
        const arr = new source.constructor(buf);
        arr.set(source);
        return arr;
    }
    return source.slice(0, newSize);
};

class DummyArray { 
    constructor();
    constructor(buffer: ArrayBuffer);
    constructor(array: ArrayLike<number>);
    constructor(arg?) { }

    // Hack to have a typed constructor property, see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841
    'constructor': typeof DummyArray;
    BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: number;
    length: number;
    [index: number]: number;

    set(array: ArrayLike<number>, offset?: number): void { }
    slice(start?: number, end?: number): this { return this; }

    static BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: number;
}

// How it intended to work
resize(new DummyArray([1, 2, 3]), 5);

// How it fails to typecheck
// Types of property 'constructor' are incompatible.
//   Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'GenericTypedArrayConstructor<Uint8Array>'.
resize(new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3]), 5);
```